# how to center align a text inside textView in RelativeLayout with a sibling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have code below which center aligns the text inside a TextView but its a hack. Please see my comment in between.

Is there a way I can achieve the same result but without the hack?

**Please note** I want ***text*** to be center aligned wrt. Screen irrespective of the width of the sibling (in case below 'action_back')

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/action_back"
    layout="@layout/action_back"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

<!--
    TODO:
    hack TextView width is set as match_parent to
    make it center align with Screen dimensions,
    which overlaps with back btn. I could
    not find another way to center it.
-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you really tried keeping TextView width as

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

and

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

together? Because other than

> android:layout_width="match_parent"

in your TextView I could not see any issue.

There is one thing to note if your Title text is long it will overlap your button. To rectify it put

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/action_back"
```

Comment: I did try this and tried again ....with these changes, text is displayed right next to back btn instead of being in middle wrt. Screen

Comment: Are you inflating/including this layout on another?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `layout_width` to `wrap_content` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` you should be able to center the text in the Relative Layout.

EDIT:
Maybe something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/action_back"
    layout="@layout/action_back"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/action_back"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is same as my soln...linearlayout takes entire width overlapping with back btn.....

Comment: Are you sure you're setting `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/action_back"` on the LinearLayout? There should be no overlap if so.

Answer (score 0):

just swap the positions of the tags. Rest seems fine to me.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <include android:id="@+id/action_back"
        layout="@layout/action_back"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```